# How to link a menu bar that will display in a container but in the same page in html?

Tags: html, hyperlink, containers, menubar, displayobject

I'm creating an ordering website with a layout like this and I'm still an amateur in creating a website so I want to ask how will I link the SIDEBAR and MENU BAR that when clicked, it will display in the container of the PRODUCTS only and in the same page like in frameset. Thank you.

HERE'S THE LINK OF MY LAYOUT:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zn2w8&s=8#.VIe0nzGUeAk

Answer (score 0):

use an a href tag on both sidebar and menu bar with an anchor set, where the a tag has classes that will be opened in an iframe like fancybox.

```
http://fancybox.net/
```